# Data and email list in two different sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have the data in the **Backend** sheet and I have the email list on **Subscribers** sheet, but the email is not sent to the list, where did I go wrong?

```
function sendEmail(e) {
var thisSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if (thisSheet.getName() !== 'Backend' || e.range.columnStart !== 17 || e.range.rowStart == 1 || e.value !== 'LOCAL') return;
var body, headers = thisSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 6)
    .getValues()[0],
    thisRow = thisSheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 6)
    .getValues()[0],
    vehicle = thisRow[3],
    vehicle2 = thisRow[4],
    subject = "⚫ Vehicle Ready "+vehicle +" "+vehicle2
    
    var emailList = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Subscribers").getRange("A2:A").getValues();
    
    body = "<i>The following vehicle is ready after wash</i><br><br>",
    i = 0;
while (i < 6) {
    body += '<font style="font-size:14px;color:grey;font-family: Arial">'+headers[i] +'</font>'+' - <b><font style="font-size:14px;font-family: Arial">' + thisRow[i] +'</font></b><br><hr width="30%" align="left" Color="#bfbfbf" size="0.75">';
    i++;
}
```

MailApp.sendEmail(emailList, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, name: "company"});
}enter code here

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification?

### Modification points:

- The values retrieved by `getValues()` is 2 dimensional array. In your case, `emailList` of `var emailList = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Subscribers").getRange("A2:A").getValues()` is like `[["email1"],["email2"],,,]`. And also, in the case of range "A2:A", no values might be included.
- At `MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`, `recipient` is a string.

By above points, such error occurs. When you want to send the email to all emails in `emailList`, it is required to use a loop. Or, when you want to use the emails in `emailList` as `cc`, it is not required to use the loop. So here, I would like to propose the following 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, all emails in `emailList` is used as `recipient`.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailList, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, name: "company"});
```

To:

```
emailList.forEach(([email]) => {
  if (email != "") {
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, name: "company"});
  }
})
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, all emails in `emailList` is used as `cc`.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailList, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, name: "company"});
```

To:

```
MailApp.sendEmail("email address", subject, body, {htmlBody: body, name: "company", cc: emailList.filter(String).toString()});
```

or

```
MailApp.sendEmail(null, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, name: "company", cc: emailList.filter(String).toString()});
```

- In this case, when `null` is used as `recipient`, the email doesn't include the email address of `to`.

### Note:

- Please use this modified script with enabling V8.

### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)